# "Script Error encountered", "'__doPostBack' is undefined" in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, browser, internet-explorer-11

Getting issue of '**__doPostBack**' is undefined" in Internet Explorer 11(**.net version 4.0**) . I already install App_Browser Update of IE & site works perfectly on IE10 & its lover versions. this issue comes on IE11.

I follow this link for changes

**http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/incorrectly-rendered-webpage-when-using-internet-explorer-11.aspx**

**http://help.ablecommerce.com/index.htm#upgrades/ac7_aspnet/tech_bulletins/asp.net_4.0_with_ie_11.htm**

Now Site working perfectly on Local(**Windows7 with IE11 browser**) no issue comes but when site is loaded on Server(**Windows Server 2003 R2**) that issue is still persists. I also installed Server Updates for IE11 fix .

Follow link for Server Update : **http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us**

But no changes reflected please give suggestion for provided issues.

Comment: can any body have a solution

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue... it stems from a bug in the 4.0 .NET framework. Essentially the framework only contains names of certain browser version ranges, and this new IE is not recognized. As a result the framework doesn't know what exactly the browser supports. Since it sees no definition, it assumes it doesn't have certain JavaScript features like post-backs.

The Best solution is to get with the times, and update to the new 4.5 .NET version (or 4.5.1)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx

If you are nervous about about changing your server framework version Microsoft also offers a hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Yesterday I updated our servers framework, and the update seems to be very reverse compatible.

I hope this helps.